# .Net Identity roles vs different entities

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have to do a .NET MVC homework, where we have a Bank with Employees who can handle Customers. Both can log in and have different actions.

How can I make Identity to work with both Employee's and Customer's models? Or should I be using roles for identifying them?

Comment: Why should I use both? Isn't that redundant? And also how can I use more IdentityUsers in one project?

Comment: What about using Identity for your MVC application and creating 2 roles (employee and customer). You can then create 2 separate registration/login pages (one for Employees and the other for Customers). Whenever a new employee is registered via the Employee login, Identity creates a new user with the employee role. When a customer registers via the Customer login, Identity creates a new user with the customer role. Then, you can use roles to allow/restrict access.